# PHP verify file before upload

Tags: php

I'm having a little problems checking the file before upload.

My current code for checking it, is the following:

```
public function verify_file(){
    $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["size"] <= 100000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Why the code above works and the code below doesn't?

```
if(($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] != "image/jpeg")
&& ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] != "image/jpg")
&& ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] != "image/pjpeg")
&& ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] != "image/x-png")
&& ($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["type"] != "image/png")
&& (!in_array($extension, $allowedExts))){
    return false;
}else{
    if($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["size"] <= 100000){
        return false;
    }

    if($_FILES["page-add-file-box"]["error"] > 0){
        return false;
    }
} 
return true;
```

I've tested and I know it fails on the first `return false`, after the `!in_array()`

Comment: PHP doesn't get the file until it's been uploaded, right?  Any pre-upload verification would be done through Javascript.

Comment: I don't think that Javascript pre-upload validation is a good idea. Any user can easily bypass it by directly sending the file to the server.

Comment: No, you never do verifications in JS, it can be turned off or a very old browser cant even "speak" it. Verifications in JS are as useless as the HTML object tag ...

Comment: Javascript is a bad idea. That's why I've changed for server side handle.

Comment: Please explain in which case your code works and in which case it do not work.

Comment: Well the reason I changed the code was to verify firstly the extension and stops there if there's any error. To verify the file size I do believe that PHP first uploads (in his own code) and then verifies if it's true or not. 

If you try to upload a file with my first piece of code, if the file have 300MB it will kind of upload the file (or sort of..you see in the bottom-left of the chrome the percentage) and then verify if the size exceeds, and I would like to avoid that.